# How to make a browser display any tag in XML as-is without using <xmp> or <pre>

Tags: ajax, xml

I am trying to display an Ajax returned xml file in String format in IE9.

Since it is in String, IE takes all xml tags as un-recognizable html tags and tosses them away. Only text data are display and it is really a mess. I can use <xmp> or <pre> but then when I save the xml by the file->save as..., the <xmp> <pre>is there. I do have the option to select all from the web page and copy paste to some text editor but in my case it is preferrable to use save as.

So I tried to escape all those < and > with entity reference in Java with StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(). But still the problem persists. Do I have it right in Java? And is there any simple way to display xml input stream (not a file) as-is in a brwoser?

Here is the Java code for Ajax service.

```
 public String retrieveXML() {

        String unescapedXML = getXMLByRestfulService();
        formatXMLMsg(unescapedXML);
        String finalXML = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(unescapedXML);

        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Here is the Ajax client code. Some parameters can be safely ignored.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();a
    } else if ( window.ActiveXObject ){
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    if ( req ) {
        req.onreadystatechange=function(){
           if ( req.readyState == READY_STATE_COMPLETE ){
              var myXML = req.responseText;
              var myWin = window.open("", "aWindow", "width=800, height=500");
              myWin.document.write("<xmp>"+myXML+"</xmp>");
              myWin.focus();
            }
        };
        req.open("POST", url, true );
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        req.send (params);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on your question in regards to "as is" in browser.  But, I'll take a shot.
You may need to enable the XML DOM plugin.

1. Click Tools(gear icon)->Manage Add-ons; this will pop-up a dialog
2. select "All add-ons". I don't have IE9 loaded, but you need to (may look like below):
   [image]
3. Find "XML DOM Document" add-on and make sure its enabled
4. Close all IE windows and retest